# Why in lua, whith metavalue __index, t = {_index} is nil?

Tags: lua, metatable

When, in lua, I run this code, the metavalue __index is nil

```
t = {__index = t}
print(t.__index)
--prints nil
```

but if I write it like this...

```
t = {}
t.__index = t
print(t.__index)
--prints table ****
```

... it works
My question is why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `t = {__index = t}` `t` is whatever you assigned to `t` befor that line. In your case you never assigend a value to `t` so `t` is a nil value.

This is basically equivalent to

```
do
   local x = t
   t = {__index = x}
end
```

As t is nil this is equivalent to

```
do
   local x = nil
   t = {__index = x}
end
```

or

```
do
   t = {__index = nil}
end
```

or

```
t = {}
```

In the second snippet

```
t = {}
t.__index = t
```

you assign an empty table to `t`. So `t.__index = t` assigns that empty table to `t.__index`

See [Visibility Rules](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.5)

> Notice that, in a declaration like local x = x, the new x being
> declared is not in scope yet, and so the second x refers to the
> outside variable.

### Edit

> sorry but I didn't understand : with t= {text = "hello"} t.text is not
> nil

`t = {text = "hello"}` is equivalent to

```
do
   local x = {}
   x.text = "hello"
   t = x
end
```

here you assign a string value. Not a nil value as in your first example.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand : with ```t= {text = "hello"}``` t.text is not nil

Comment: Maybe an explicit `t = nil` will help to visualize the default case?